# Create Folder In Internal Storage With small Icon

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

How can I create folder in internal storage with small icon in android stdio ?

like what's app in this image:

[image]

Comment: The "folder" does not have an icon. The file manager app that you are using happens to display an icon for that particular folder. You would need to contact the developers of that file manager, learn what algorithm they use for deciding whether to display an icon, then see if that algorithm can be adapted to your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [File.mkdirs()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) method.

Something like this:

```
final File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "subdirectory");

if (!file.exists()) {
    sub.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! but  I want with folder small icon.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but the command to build it is in the hands of certain people like Whatsapp 
You must contact them for access 
Definitely not done with `File` and .. and in my opinion it is set in the `AndroidManifest.xml` section ...